# How to add symbol or text to php variable

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a shortcode for woocommerce, I was wondering how I can add some text just before the `$order_id` variable.

**Current code**

```
<div class="items_orders_card"> <span class="items_title">Order</span> '. $order_id .' </div>
```

**Current output is** Order: 39800

**Output I want to get** Order: #39800

I would like to add the pound sign (#) just before the number. Is there a specific way to do this? Also, does the same rule apply to text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use

```
<div class="items_orders_card"> <span class="items_title">Order</span> #'. $order_id .' </div>
```

or

```
<div class="items_orders_card"> <span class="items_title">Order</span> '. sprintf("#%d", $order_id) .' </div>
```